# Using CSR to hide field on list view but show on quick edit view

Tags: jslink, client-side-rendering, quick-edit

Is it possible to use the "ShowInGrid=True" element of the URL to act as a trigger for show/hiding a field in a datasheet view?

The below code that will hide it nicely on the default allitems view but i would like that to be field to be visible on the quickedit view.

(function () {

```
function RemoveFields(ctx) {
    var fieldName = "Date"; // here Date is field or column name to be hide
    var header = document.querySelectorAll("[displayname=" + fieldName + "]")[0].parentNode;
    var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
    header.style.display = "none";
    for (var i = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(" + index + ")"); i < cells.length; i++) {
        cells[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}

function registerRenderer() {
    var ctxForm = {};
    ctxForm.Templates = {};
    ctxForm.OnPostRender = RemoveFields;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');
```

(Source https://riptutorial.com/sharepoint/example/26699/hide-column-from-sharepoint-list-view-using-csr-)

If hiding is not an option can the field be obfuscated/md5'd instead on the list view?

I can see how other examples on the non quick edit views will work by highlighting the form and using the ("NewForm": hideField) notation (from Dylan Christy) but getting it to appear for quick edit is causing me problems

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually got it working

In the end it was pretty simple but  still took some figuring out credit goes to avishnyakov and the SPDev codeplex site

Hope this helps someone

```
(function () 
{
   function ClientNameToggle(ctx) 
 {var fieldName = "ClientName"; // here Date is field or column name to be hide
var header = document.querySelectorAll("[name=" + fieldName + "]")[0].parentNode;
    var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;

    if(ctx.inGridMode === true)
{
    header.style.display = "table-cell";

        for (var i = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(" + index + ")"); i < cells.length; i++) 
    {
            cells[i].style.display = "table-cell";
    }
}
else 
{
    header.style.display = "none";

        for (var i = 0, cells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(" + index + ")"); i < cells.length; i++) 
    {
            cells[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    }

}

function registerRenderer() 
{
    var ctxForm = {};
    ctxForm.Templates = {};
    ctxForm.OnPostRender = ClientNameToggle;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');
```

})();